# Need to remove some element positions in a list of lists, is there a more efficient way to this without making new output list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-manipulation

I have a list called "candidate_keywords_all" containing three inner lists of strings. The other list of lists called "positions_to_remove_all" has index positions of words to be removed. My code below does this by making a new output list. Is there a way without using a new list? If I modify original list using pop method, each pop affects the index positions of remaining elements and they no longer match up and cause index errors. Note that the inner list for positions can be empty too.

```
candidate_keywords_all =[
    ['list1_word1', 'list1_word2', 'list1_word3'],
    ['list2_word1', 'list2_word2', 'list2_word3', 'list2_word4', 'list2_word5', 'list2_word6'],
    ['list3_word1', 'list3_word2']
]

positions_to_remove_all =[ [0, 2], [1, 3, 5], [] ]

## extract the Selected keywords into new data structure
final_keywords = []
for each_index_positions, each_candidate_keywords in \
    zip(positions_to_remove_all, candidate_keywords_all):
    temp_arr = [keyword for idx, keyword in enumerate(each_candidate_keywords) if idx not in each_index_positions]
    final_keywords.append(temp_arr)

for each_candidate_keywords, each_index_positions, each_final_keywords in zip(candidate_keywords_all, positions_to_remove_all, final_keywords):
    print(f"BEFORE = {each_candidate_keywords}\nRemove positions = {each_index_positions}\nAFTER = {each_final_keywords}\n\n")
```

Any inputs appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I hope you're aware that every time you pop an element list is reindexed which is costly. That's why I recommend creating a new list instead of deleting elements from the existing list.

Comment: Yup agreed pop or del would do that, which is ok for me. Actually there is quite a bit of data in the list. This was a simplified version of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `del` to remove an element by index directly from a list, in-place.
Note I iterate the positions in reverse order because otherwise after removal the remaining indexes all change places.

```py
for each_index_positions, each_candidate_keywords in zip(
    positions_to_remove_all, candidate_keywords_all
):
    for pos in reversed(each_index_positions):
        del each_candidate_keywords[pos]
```

Comment: Elegant solution, thank you! Wish I'd thought of it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

In all scenarios, you have to iterate through your lists. So you can't gain any performance here but you can write it with a single list comprehension if you are concerned about the number of lines:

```
final_keywords = [[item for j, item in enumerate(sublist) if j not in positions_to_remove_all[i]]
                  for i, sublist in enumerate(candidate_keywords_all)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But double list comprehension wasn't the primary concern. Doing it without making a new data structure was. @Adam.Er8 solution fits perfectly, even though list reversal may cost a bit of time.